# Example of two primitives

Tags: integration

I've been trying to better understand the primitives of the function $ f(x)=1/x^3 $​ defined on the interval $ R−{0} $. In my research, I attempted to find two primitives that do not differ by a constant, but I couldn't come up with a satisfactory example.

In my attempt to find two primitives that do not differ by a constant, I experimented with some ideas, but I couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

For example, I tried to directly integrate the function and obtained $−1/2x^2+C1$​ as the first primitive. However, I couldn't find a second primitive that differs from this one by a constant. It seems that all the primitives I can find are equivalent.

Could you please provide me with an example of two primitives of this function that meet the required criterion? I need this clarification for a project I'm working on..

Comment: $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is not an interval.

Comment: $-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{x}{|x|}$

Comment: Is there a typo in your posting?  In the first paragraph, "...I attempted to find two primitives that do not differ by a constant...".  Later in the posting, "...However, I couldn't find a second primitive that differs from this one by a constant...".  So, which is it?  Do you want the primitives to differ by a constant or not differ by a constant?